# Pyspark: sum over a window based on a condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window

Consider the simple DataFrame:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Trial').getOrCreate()

simpleData = (("2000-04-17", "144", 1), \
    ("2000-07-06", "015", 1),  \
    ("2001-01-23", "015", -1),   \
    ("2001-01-18", "144", -1),  \
    ("2001-04-17", "198", 1),    \
    ("2001-04-18", "036", -1),  \
    ("2001-04-19", "012", -1),    \
    ("2001-04-19", "188", 1), \
    ("2001-04-25", "188", 1),\
    ("2001-04-27", "015", 1) \
  )
 
columns= ["dates", "id", "eps"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Out:

```
root
 |-- dates: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- eps: long (nullable = true)

+----------+---+---+
|dates     |id |eps|
+----------+---+---+
|2000-04-17|144|1  |
|2000-07-06|015|1  |
|2001-01-23|015|-1 |
|2001-01-18|144|-1 |
|2001-04-17|198|1  |
|2001-04-18|036|-1 |
|2001-04-19|012|-1 |
|2001-04-19|188|1  |
|2001-04-25|188|1  |
|2001-04-27|015|1  |
+----------+---+---+
```

I would like to sum the values in the `eps` column over a rolling window keeping only the last value for any given ID in the `id` column. For example, defining a window of 5 rows and assuming we are on 2001-04-17, I want to sum only the last `eps` value for each given unique ID. In the 5 rows we have only 3 different ID, so the sum must be of 3 elements: -1 for the ID 144 (forth row), -1 for the ID 015 (third row) and 1 for the ID 198 (fifth row) for a total of -1.

In my mind, within the rolling window I should do something like `F.sum(groupBy('id').agg(F.last('eps')))` that of course is not possible to achieve in a rolling window.

I obtained the desired result using a UDF.

```
@pandas_udf(IntegerType(), PandasUDFType.GROUPEDAGG)
def fun_sum(id, eps):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['id'] = id
    df['eps'] = eps
    value = df.groupby('id').last().sum()
    return value
```

And then:

```
w = Window.orderBy('dates').rowsBetween(-5,0)
df = df.withColumn('sum', fun_sum(F.col('id'), F.col('eps')).over(w))
```

The problem is that my dataset contains more than 8 milion rows and performing this task with this UDF takes about 2 hours.

I was wandering whether there is a way to achieve the same result with built-in PySpark functions avoiding using a UDF or at least whether there is a way to improve the performance of my UDF.

For completeness, the desired output should be:

```
+----------+---+---+----+
|dates     |id |eps|sum |
+----------+---+---+----+
|2000-04-17|144|1  |1   |
|2000-07-06|015|1  |2   |
|2001-01-23|015|-1 |0   |
|2001-01-18|144|-1 |-2  |
|2001-04-17|198|1  |-1  |
|2001-04-18|036|-1 |-2  |
|2001-04-19|012|-1 |-3  |
|2001-04-19|188|1  |-1  |
|2001-04-25|188|1  |0   |
|2001-04-27|015|1  |0   |
+----------+---+---+----+
```

EDIT: the rseult must also be achievable using a `.rangeBetween()` window.

Answer (score 2):

In case you haven't figured it out yet, here's one way of achieving it.

Assuming that `df` is defined and initialised the way you defined and initialised it in your question.

Import the required functions and classes:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, col
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
```

Create the necessary [`WindowSpec`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html#pyspark.sql.Window):

```python
window_spec = (
    Window
    # Partition by 'id'.
    .partitionBy(df.id)
    # Order by 'dates', latest dates first.
    .orderBy(df.dates.desc())
)
```

Create a `DataFrame` with partitioned data:

```python
partitioned_df = (
    df
    # Use the window function 'row_number()' to populate a new column
    # containing a sequential number starting at 1 within a window partition.
    .withColumn('row', row_number().over(window_spec))
    # Only select the first entry in each partition (i.e. the latest date).
    .where(col('row') == 1)
)
```

Just in case you want to double-check the data:

```python
partitioned_df.show()

# +----------+---+---+---+
# |     dates| id|eps|row|
# +----------+---+---+---+
# |2001-04-19|012| -1|  1|
# |2001-04-25|188|  1|  1|
# |2001-04-27|015|  1|  1|
# |2001-04-17|198|  1|  1|
# |2001-01-18|144| -1|  1|
# |2001-04-18|036| -1|  1|
# +----------+---+---+---+
```

[Group](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy) and [aggregate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sum.html#pyspark.sql.functions.sum) the data:

```python
sum_rows = (
    partitioned_df
    # Aggragate data.
    .groupBy()
    # Sum all rows in 'eps' column.
    .sum('eps')
    # Get all records as a list of Rows.
    .collect()
)
```

Get the result:

```python
print(f"sum eps: {sum_rows[0][0]})
# sum eps: 0
```